# How can I make the cheque for my bank account closing balance usable by someone else?

Tags: united-kingdom, check, endorsement

When closing my UK bank account and moving abroad, I got a cheque from my building society that states

> Pay *MR F M ANAPHORY ************
>
> The Sum of (Not exceeding ten thousand pounds unless countersigned)
>
> *TEN POUNDS 38*
>
> For and on behalf of X Building Society
>
> [ACCOUNT PAYEE ONLY]

I would like to give this cheque to someone else to pay into their account. The cheque states “Account Payee Only”, but obviously I don't have a UK account any more, and I'm not in the UK to open one.

Is there any way I can send it to someone in the UK, so that they can use it to get the £10.38 into their account?

Answer (score 4):

According to the people responsible for the cheque and credit clearing system, no:

https://www.chequeandcredit.co.uk/information-hub/faqs/crossed-cheques

> **Is there any situation where a crossed cheque can be paid into the account of someone other than the named payee or recipient?**
>
> Not for a cheque crossed ‘A/C Payee Only’ or ‘A/C Payee’. The Cheques
>   Act 1992 and Section 81 of the Bills of Exchange Act 1882 give
>   statutory power to the ‘A/C Payee Only’ or ‘A/C Payee’ crossing when
>   it is used. The legislation means that a cheque which bears the ‘A/C
>   Payee Only’ crossing can only be paid into an account in the name of
>   the person who has received the cheque (i.e. the payee) exactly as it
>   appears on the cheque.

I think your best option is to contact the building society and ask if there's any other alternative for receiving your money. For example, if they would do a bank transfer instead, then you could use a money transfer service like [Revolut](https://blog.revolut.com/introducing-revolut-current-accounts/) or [Transferwise](https://transferwise.com/gb/borderless/), who both offer UK accounts in your name, to receive the money and then transfer it on.

But for £10 it's going to be difficult to find anything worthwhile, particularly now that the cheque has already been issued and would need to be cancelled.